# How to use neutral language in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, resources, resx

I am facing the following issue:

- I have translated my application into different languages using resx files. I want to use the same resx files in other apps as well.
- For different apps, I should be able to change the default language (some apps will only be available in Spanish, others only in English, and others multilingual)

I figured I could just name the resources LanguageStrings.es.resx and LanguageStrings.en.resx, and use NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute to set the default language of the app.

However, when there is no LanguageStrings.resx (invariant file) in the app, the application seems to break (MissingManifestResourceException). I thought the Resource Manager should use the setting in NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute to find the correct resource (for example; fall back to Spanish) instead of looking for a neutral file.

Is my assumption correct and am I running into a platform bug? I have noticed that [ResourceManager.GetNeutralResourcesLanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getneutralresourceslanguage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) doesn't returned the language defined using NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute, but invariant culture instead

Answer (score 2):

Without a invariant resource file (`LanguageStrings.resx`), the compiler won't pick it up. You should let the English resource file (Currently `LanguageStrings.en.resx`) be the invariant file, ie. without **.en**  in the filename, and then set

`[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]`

All .NET applications work this way. It's not a unique "issue" to Windows Phone.

Comment: The problem with this is that for different applications (using the same resource files) I want a different NeutralResourceLanguage. The compiler does pick it up without invariant resource file, as long as I keep the generated .cs file and keep that updated.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using another language than English for the Invariant file. Just make sure the `NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute` matches the Invariant language. Also, without a invariant resource file, the compiler picks the *first added resource file* as Invariant. Not really a good way to structure your code!

Comment: Yes, but I want to use different default languages in different apps (but keep using the same files). Shouldn't I be able to just set another default using NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute? (instead of having to rename x.es.resx to x.resx for all spanish-only apps)

Comment: Why do you want to *force* the language onto the user? If the user picks Spanish as locale, they'll get the correct file, no matter what you set as invariant.

Comment: One of the reasons is the Marketplace seems to look at NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute to determine the languages used in the application. Which means if it is set to English, even though <supportedCultures> only specifies Spanish, I'll still have to provide metadata for both English and Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you specify your language as supported in the  element in your csproj - you need to have the resx that you are trying to use in the supported culture. If you use the language that is supposedly supported and the resx is not there - you will get a MissingManifestResourceException. Neutral language will be picked up if the current language is not supported.